# Apache Kafka: TimeoutException and then nothing works‏

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to send a message from a producer to a kafka node in another DC.
Both the producer and consumer are set with the default `0.10.0.0` configuration and the message sizes are not so small (around 500k).
Most of the time when sending messages I am encountered with these exceptions:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for topic-0
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.

And after that no more messages get transferred (even the callback for remaining messages is not getting called).

Comment: You should check the server.properties whether you configured:  listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092 correct or not.

Comment: It is correct and the port is open

Comment: I found https://blog.csdn.net/fst438060684/article/details/82144653
detailed explanation is here you have to chose which solution can works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Kafka documentation:

> A small batch size will make batching less common and may reduce throughput (a batch size of zero will disable batching entirely). A very large batch size may use memory a bit more wastefully as we will always allocate a buffer of the specified batch size in anticipation of additional records.

Set `batch.size = 0`, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why it happens?

Comment: According to Kafka documentation  "A small batch size will make batching less common and may reduce throughput **(a batch size of zero will disable batching entirely)**. A very large batch size may use memory a bit more wastefully as we will always allocate a buffer of the specified batch size in anticipation of additional records."

Comment: But why batching leads to this problem?

Comment: Answer itself is in your question, you are getting memory allocation problem, the main reason to set this low is lack of memory – Kafka will always allocate enough memory for the entire batch size.

Comment: But the default batch size is very small(16Kib)
Why should Kafka fail to allocate that much it's really a tiny amount of memory

Comment: @Aby reducing batch.size never helps. This ultimately affects throughput and latency.

Comment: reducing batch.size never helps. This ultimately affects throughput and latency

Comment: @HarshVardhanLadha, it helped in my case, so I shared the information.

Comment: @AbhayDixit Even if I make batch.size = 0 still i am getting this @ producer side...what should i do 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for  609 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to chime in because I received the exact same errors today.  I tried increasing the `request.timeout.ms`, decreasing `batch.size`, and even setting the `batch.size` to zero.  However, nothing worked.

It turned out it was because the server couldn't connect to one of the 10 Kafka cluster nodes.  So, what I saw were some inappropriate exceptions being thrown.  By the way, we are using Kafka 0.9.0.1 if it matters.